# how to show the Scrollbar below the Sidenav Toolbar in AngularMaterial-7

Tags: angular, scrollbar, angular-material-7

[image]**Please help me to achieve the below two methods:**

1) How to show the sidenav **scrollbar below the toolbar** in the sidenav:

2) Also how to **show** the Scrollbar **only when we move the mouse cursor** over the side nav.

### Thanks in advance.!

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <!-- SIDENAV -->
  <mat-sidenav [mode]="showLeftNAV ? 'side' : 'over'" [opened]="showLeftNAV" class="mat-elevation-z10" style="width:312px;border: 0px;">
    <!-- SIDENAV-HEADER-TOOLBAR -->
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height:112px;position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 10;">HELLO</mat-toolbar>
    <!--SIDENAV-BODY-CONTENT -->
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
    <h4 mat-line>SAMPLE TEXT</h4>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <!-- CONTENT -->
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- CONTENT-TOOLBAR -->
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height:112px;position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 10;">
      CONTENT-AREA
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need turn off scrolling in the sidenav and turn in on for only the scrollable content which is everything except the toolbar (all your h4s). To do that, add a DIV around the scrollable content below the toolbar, and apply style to fix the height of the toolbar and allow the scrollable section to fill the remaining space inside a flexbox.

```
<mat-toolbar style="flex: 0 0 128px;">HELLO</mat-toolbar>
<div style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <!- menu content -->
</div>
```

Also add some style to the menu content container to turn off vertical scrolling and provide the flexbox layout for the menu content.

```
.no-v-scroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

In Angular Material v6 you can apply that style directly to `mat-sidenav`:

```
<mat-sidenav class="no-v-scroll" style="width: 320px;">
  <mat-toolbar style="flex: 0 0 128px;">HELLO</mat-toolbar>
  <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <!- menu content -->
  </div>
</mat-sidenav>
```

But in v7 an extra DIV is needed around the menu content (toolbar plus scrollable):

```
<mat-sidenav style="width: 320px;">
  <div class="no-v-scroll">
    <mat-toolbar style="flex: 0 0 128px;">HELLO</mat-toolbar>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
      <!- menu content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav>
```

As mentioned in the OP's answer, you can also override the `mat-drawer-inner-container` class if you don't want to add this extra DIV.

Here is the OP's modified code for [v6 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-57nrsu?file=app%2Fsidenav-overview-example.html).

Here is the OP's modified code for [v7 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpkv9t?file=app%2Fsidenav-disable-close-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

**@G.Tranter** Dear sir,

Actually, I'm **using** Angular Material-**7**,
I've **mistakenly** posted it under Angular-**6**,

Your solution **worked** on Angular-**6**,
But **Not** on Angular-**7**,

After inspecting, I've found out Angular-7, additionally adds **mat-drawer-inner-container** inside the Sidenav.

A similar question was also raised about the **mat-drawer-inner-container** in the below link
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13983

So now, in the **app.component.scss** I've added the below style to make it work.

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
```

Comment: Yes - that works - but there's another way that doesn't require overriding that style. I've updated my answer.